# Forbidden capacitance in LC circuit connected to AC source

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, capacitance, inductance

While solving problems on AC circuits, I came across one that had a circuit connection as shown below.

[image]

The question was to find the value of "the capacitance that can never be used in this circuit". The AC source used was 220V, 50Hz and it was assumed, $\pi^{2}=10$.

As far as the solution was concerned,

First, I assumed that, $I = Ae^{jwt},    
 j=\sqrt{-1} , A \in C$

Then by KVL(and assuming that initially charge on capacitor is 0),

$\frac{\int_{0}^{t} I \,dt}{C} + L\frac{dI}{dt} = Ee^{jwt} $

Where $E=220V$,

And then on differentiating and substituting the value of I, obtained,

$ A j(wL-\frac{1}{wC}) = E $

If $C=10\mu F$,
The RHS would vanish which would cause an exception here which led me to believe this was the capacitance which could not be used, and the book does say that it is the correct answer.
However, can anyone shed light upon what's happening here, physically?

Note : As I am pretty new to AC circuits I assumed that current would always vary as $I=Ae^{jwt}$
, without any prior justification. I would appreciate it if someone clarified the validity of this assumption.

Comment: Why the close vote? This is not a "check my work" question, but an "I know my work is OK, but I don't understand why" conceptual question, provoked by a typical terrible textbook treatment of physics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an odd question. What you've correctly found is that for the idealized whiteboard problem you have a perfect resonance that draws a divergent current from the source. But so what? Divergence doesn't cause the whiteboard to fail: it's a perfectly reasonable mathematical result.

In real physics, the components won't be perfect: the LC resonance won't be perfectly tuned to 50 Hz, and there will be resistance in the circuit. So, you'll draw a relatively large current from the source, but it won't diverge in a realistic model. Circuits like this are employed when drawing a large current from the source is desired. So, "can never be used" is ridiculous.

As for using a complex current as a tool to solve the system, see [phasors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phasor). Your approach is fine, and is a common approach for problems like this. Congratulations on figuring it out for yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! My thoughts were somewhere between "the current is not going to vary as it normally does" or an infinitely(mathematically) large current. Thanks for your much appreciated input.

Comment: A reason for "it *should* not be used" when connected to the mains supply is that large currents would flow but no energy would be dissipated in the circuit ie not register on the electricity supply meter,  However there would be energy loss in the transmission cables with no financial recompense to the utility company.

Comment: @Farcher Bad choices are always possible in specific cases, but what's bad in one case may be good in a different case, so "never" doesn't make sense.